# Angular - why is not serving HTML and CSS page as normal?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have working example of a Menu. It consists of 1 `index.html` file and 1 `style.css` file. It works fine when I open `index.html` file directly in any browser (it loads CSS file and displays menu without issues).

Then I tried to port that html/css to Angular app.

Created new Angular 6 project with `ng create test` and content of  `app.component.html` replaced with whole `index.html` and content of `app.component.css` replaced with content of `style.css`.

Started Angular app with `ng serve` but screen shows partial of styles and menu does not act normal (e.g. click on a button and nothing happens).

What is the correct approach to port 1 html page and 1 css to angular app so that can show 100% the same as running without Angular?

Comment: It would be great if you could post some code which you tried. Also, a screenshot would be much more helpful than describing the output like *"partial of styles and menus does not act normal"*.

Comment: It is a code of 300+ lines each. What is the general approach of porting HTML/CSS to Angular? Is it just putting html inside app.component.html and css into app.component.css and make sure links are valid? If you have any hints (besides copy/paste/update links and try again) - that could help..

Comment: @Joe, app.component.html  must be only the part "inside" body tags. take a look to https://angular.io/guide/router#routing--navigation to routing

Comment: There are more than just putting HTML and CSS into the component. Have you implemented router or ngModule? Whats in your app.component.ts? Try to provide relevant bits of your code. No need for the whole project. Or try to use [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwhece) to reproduce the functionality.

Comment: If your css targets anything outside of the component, it won't be applied. You can try dumping the css into the global `style.css`...but I'd highly encourage you to look at your app and actually build it with Angular instead of 'porting'.